# graphviz: Different orientation of the sub graphs

Tags: graphviz

I would like to create graph with 3 sub graphs. Could two of them have left-right orientation and third top-bottom orientation as in this example?

[image: Graph Example]

I need also connect a few nodes from one subgraph to another but this should be easy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible with graphviz. [`rankdir`](http://www.graphviz.org/content/attrs) is a graph attribute (not subgraph or cluster).